# PDF.js does not redirect to pdf file located on another server with CORS enabled in Firefox

Tags: javascript, scala, spring-mvc, amazon-s3, pdf.js

I got a website i need to improve. This site contains pdf files unique to each user, and PDF.js library is used to allow users viewing them. Those pdf files are generated automatically by first call by link like `httр://website.com/api/client/255/product/90/livePdfPreviewFile` which returns `Content-Type: application/pdf`, then generated file will be cached in Amazon S3 storage - after the next call by the same link it will be downloaded from AS3 by my server and given to client for preview instead of re-generating. So link is passed as GET-parameter to PDF.js script like this:

```
httр://website.com//resources/web/viewer.html?file=api%2Fclient%2F255%2Fproduct%2F90%2FlivePdfPreviewFile
```

and everything works fine, but I had to reduce server load and simply redirect my server's response directly to file in Amazon S3 storage instead of using my server as gateway for those files. I have configured CORS settings using AmazonS3 API (this is simple configuration without allowed and exposed headers mentioning, but it works with Google Chrome):

```
val config = new BucketCrossOriginConfiguration()
val rules = new java.util.ArrayList[CORSRule]()

val bucketCORSRule = new CORSRule().withId(CORS_NAME)
  .withAllowedOrigins(util.Arrays.asList("*"))
  .withAllowedMethods(util.Arrays.asList(CORSRule.AllowedMethods.GET))

rules.add(bucketCORSRule)
config.setRules(rules)
s3Client.setBucketCrossOriginConfiguration(bucketName, config)
```

Then I have changed code responsible for returning pdf file to client so it could redirect to cached file:

```
if (isResourceCached(pdf)) {
    response.sendRedirect(getDirectLinkToCache(pdf))
} else {
    response.setContentType("application/pdf")
    val renderedPdf = renderPdf(productId)
    cachePdf(renderedPdf)
    val out = response.getOutputStream
    IOUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(renderedPdf.toByteArray), out)
    out.flush()
    out.close()
}
```

But there is the problem - those redirections do not work in Firefox, but work fine in other browsers such as Google Chrome! When I pass file to PDF.js located directly in AS3 storage it works for Firefox too, also it works when file is not cached in AS3 and pdf-generating link returns pdf file instead of redirection. I tried to set other CORS parameters, but then I realized that Firefox does not even try to perform any queries to AS3 server.

This is what Chrome does. First query:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/client/255/product/90/livePdfPreviewFile
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found

Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Cache-Control:no-store
Content-Length:0
Date:Thu, 03 Sep 2015 08:06:01 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Location:http://bucket-local.s3.amazonaws.com/product-preview-pdfs/90-255.pdf
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1

Request Headers
view source
Accept:*//*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=856CF2090D14BC3E6C869CD5158CAF40
Host:127.0.0.1:8080
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8080/resources/web/viewer.html?file=%2Fapi%2Fclient%2F255%2Fproduct%2F90%2FlivePdfPreviewFile
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
```

And receiving file which location we have obtained by query above:

```
Remote Address:54.231.176.29:80
Request URL:http://bucket-local.s3.amazonaws.com/product-preview-pdfs/90-255.pdf
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Response Headers
view source
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:26263
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Date:Thu, 03 Sep 2015 08:11:45 GMT
ETag:"04a1c8853281706a478ce60080c3435f"
Last-Modified:Wed, 02 Sep 2015 07:29:41 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
Vary:Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
x-amz-expiration:expiry-date="Fri, 04 Sep 2015 00:00:00 GMT", rule-id="Delete pdfs in 1 day"
x-amz-id-2:YgGqaaIZ73tsnKhUdffU5Mit3nfFLx7dyX1or7redDN2TRjGK2e1AraE5Ks8Zy3oFavlyI3LNSc=
x-amz-request-id:BA7DA8570C9E7D32

Request Headers
view source
Accept:*//*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:bucket-local.s3.amazonaws.com
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8080
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8080/resources/web/viewer.html?file=%2Fapi%2Fclient%2F255%2Fproduct%2F90%2FlivePdfPreviewFile
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
```

After that Pdf is shown perfectly in browser. But Firefox does not even try to perform redirection. All this browser does is receiving 302 from my server, after that it does nothing. It doesn't even try to perform any queries to AS3.

So this response for a first query is all I've got:

```
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/client/255/product/90/livePdfPreviewFile
Request Method:     GET
Status Code:    HTTP/1.1 302 Found

Request Headers 10:16:05.000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Referer:    http://127.0.0.1:8080/resources/js/pdfjs/pdf.worker.js
Host:   127.0.0.1:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*//*;q=0.8
Sent Cookie
JSESSIONID: EB6EC83CFE958FF3FD994A61A4CC7CDE

Response Headers Δ1546ms
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
Location:   http://bucket-local.s3.amazonaws.com/product-preview-pdfs/90-255.pdf
Expires:    Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Date:   Thu, 03 Sep 2015 07:16:06 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control:  no-cache, no-store
```

And that was the last query Firefox has performed, nothing more in Console and Network tabs of Firebug.

Instead PDF.js does this:

> PDF.js v1.0.1040 (build: 997096f) Message: Unexpected server response
>   (0) while retrieving PDF
>   "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/client/255/product/90/livePdfPreviewFile".

So why does not Firefox even try to perform query to file which location was obtained by redirection? I have debugged javascript of PDF.js, but looks like Firefox throws exception on `self.load` and handles it as "Unexpected server response" lately:

```
PDFJS.getDocument(parameters, pdfDataRangeTransport, passwordNeeded,
                getDocumentProgress).then(
            function getDocumentCallback(pdfDocument) {
                self.load(pdfDocument, scale);
                self.loading = false;
            }, ... <handlers>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce that with regular XHR request? (PDF.js is using that under the hood)

Comment: I forced `PDFJS.disableWorker` to `true` and now it works

Comment: Your solution is not really addresses the issue and forces PDF.js to work in sub-optimal mode. You can reproduce that with regular XHR request in the worker (if redirect is used with CORS). It is reported as a bug for Firefox at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1206121

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. The 302 to another host using CORS only worked correctly on Chrome. The change that allowed it to work on Firefox and IE (Safari so far still doesn't work) was including all the source up front.

Before I had

```
<script src="bower_components/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js"></script>
<script>
   PDFJS.workerSrc = 'bower_components/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js'
</script>
```

After the change

```
<script src="bower_components/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.combined.js"></script>
```

Good luck.

**Update**

Turns out using pdf.combined.js effectively turns off the webworker for rendering as one of the answers above suggested.

But there is a way to get it to work with webworkers enabled with the use of Blob and URL.createObjectURL. Take a look here

http://colonelpanic.net/2014/08/using-pdf-js-web-worker-cross-domain-cors/

**Update 2**

The page can still be accessed here https://web.archive.org/web/20211019021310/http://colonelpanic.net/2014/08/using-pdf-js-web-worker-cross-domain-cors/

Comment: Would be cool if you posted the explaination here instead of linking to a site that no longer works :(

Comment: I promise it worked when I put the link :) It was so long ago some kids born on that day may already be trying to write code. You can still find it here https://web.archive.org/web/20211019021310/http://colonelpanic.net/2014/08/using-pdf-js-web-worker-cross-domain-cors/